# Express the quantity as a single logarithm: $ \frac 13 \ln (x+2)^3 + \frac 12[ \ln x - \ln (x^2+3x+ 2)^2]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Express the quantity as a single logarithm: $ \frac 13 \ln (x+2)^3 + \frac 12[ \ln x - \ln (x^2+3x+ 2)^2]$

[image]

The answer in the book is ln $\frac {\sqrt{x}}{x+1}$

If am not allowed to to cancel terms when they are sums, how was this answered calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for $x>0$ we get $$\log(x+2)+\log(x^{1/2})-\log(x^2+3x+2)=\log((x+2)x^{1/2})-\log(x^2+3x+2)$$ and finally we get $$\log\left(\frac{(x+2)x^{1/2}}{x^2+3x+2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rule $\ln A + \ln B = \ln (AB)$.

Comment: this is true only for $A>0,B>0$

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake lies in the division. It's true that:
$$-\log x = \log x^{-1}=\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
It is ***not*** however true that:
$$-\log x = \frac{1}{\log x}$$

In other words, your third line should read:
$$\ln (x+2) + \ln \sqrt{x} - \ln \frac{1}{x^2+3x+2}$$
$$=\ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{x}(x+2)}{x^2+3x+2}\right)$$
Can you continue from there?